# Просьба помочь в написании компонента, при удалении с формы он вызывает AV

Tags: delphi, компоненты, vcl

1. Устанавливает компонент в IDE (PakPanelTest.dpk), после этого открывает
   в Delphi демо-проект (PakPanelTest.dpk).
2. В дизайнере устанавливаем свойство TestPanel1.ExternalToolBarPanel = SuperPanel
3. Удаляем в дизайнере SuperPanel.

По идее кнопка "M" должна была удалиться с SuperPanel (вызов метода
DestroyToolBar из SetExternalToolBarPanel), а потом создатся заново на
внутренней панеле (вызов метода из CreateToolBar из
SetExternalToolBarPanel).
Но вместо этого происходит AV на строке FreeAndNil(FTestSpeedButton)
метода DestroyToolBar. Почему происходит AV понять не могу.
Очень нужна помощь.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HeUsyxr4epUZ6_etJw3Q-Mtka3VrLLSF

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

1. При создании FTestSpeedButton указывайте овнером не себя, а FToolBarPanel:

   ```
   FTestSpeedButton := TSpeedButton.Create(FToolBarPanel);
   ```
2. FreeAndNil(FTestSpeedButton); - вообще уберите из метода DestroyToolBar.

Тогда по идее кнопка автоматом будет удаляться вместе с удалением своего овнера. А сейчас получается что кнопка удалилась при удалении панели и теперь хочет удалиться ещё раз.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую и тут отпишу результат.  Хотел бы уточнить: А если овнером кнопки сделать nil ? И еще момент: Когда срабатывает Notification - до удаление FExternalToolBarPanel (т.е. он еще существует) или после) ?

Comment: Если сделаете nil, то тогда ваша изначальная логика возможно будет срабатывать. Но я бы так не делал. VCL несёт в себе некую логику, систему, правила взаимодействия родительских и вложенных окон. Если вы сделаете nil, тогда вам самим нужно гарантировать удаление кнопки даже когда она лежит на внешнем элементе. Немного не понял про Notification... Возможно вы имели ввиду Exception? Но в любом случае - я не запускал под отладкой, это вы сможете отследить сами.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Но ответы на вопросы в моем предыдущем комментарии все таки хотелось бы получить.